# WYSISYG-редактор для Django

Tags: django

Нужен wysiwyg-редактор для сайта на django. Какое приложение посоветуете? Желательно с хорошей инструкцией по установке и использованию.

Comment: Спасибо всем, решил остановиться на Django-MarkItUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wysiwyg` это же `javascript` - ставьте любой, какой больше нравится… Один из самых популярных - `TinyMCE`.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - можно заюзать markdown и в шаблонах просто рендерить его. Среди плюсов - понятный синтаксис, "голый" текст без всяких там инлайн-стилей и прочего. Среди минусов - возможно, ограниченность в плане возможных "украшательств" текста. Но оно вам надо?

В качестве приложения под это дело можно заюзать [django_markdown](https://github.com/klen/django_markdown) с интегрированным WYSIWYG-редактором, интеграцией в flatpages и некоторыми другими штуками

Answer (score 1):

Есть приложение [Django-TinyMCE](http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/)

Comment: Не советую :)

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста почему? Я конечно сам вообще не сторонник WYSIWYG-редакторов в принципе, потому что они все кривые. Я предпочитаю редактировать чистый HTML всегда, но все таки интересно Ваше мнение. Сам я использовал Django-TinyMCE в парочке проектов, настройка у него довольно гибкая...

Comment: Я тоже использовал в парочке проектов. Но - вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Они - все кривые